# How to determine the clockwise order of triangles based on their vertices in Python

Tags: python, computational-geometry

I have several instances of Triangle that look something like this: `Triangle([1, 3, 2], [30, 40, 90])`. The first list are labels for each point, and the second are the angles of the vertices.  If I have five triangles like this, how can I tell the clockwise order that they are in?  For example,

```
Triangle([2, 3, 4], [50, 30, 100])  # A
Triangle([8, 4, 3], [30, 80, 70])   # B
Triangle([1, 3, 2], [30, 70, 80])   # C
```

Is there a way to tell their clockwise orientation around the point labelled 3?

Answer (score 1):

No. Below are two valid representations of your sample triangles. One is a reflection of the other, and the order of the triangles going clockwise around point 3 is reversed. Thus the problem is ambiguous and more information is needed.

[image]